# encode and decode data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to view data from backend (services) which is encrpted. I am trying to use base64 decode and base64 encode to view the service data and send data. 
but base64 has encoding and decoding the  data that contains these tokens."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=". but my backend data has other tokens. Is there any encode and decode methods?

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript can do this in most browsers at this point.
Use the [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) methods provided, like `btoa()` and `atob()`. This may not be supported in all older versions of browsers, so you may just have to look up a simple algorithm for converting. I don't think AngularJS has something implemented specifically for this, simply because it's already widely handled.